# No logs in Loki (official tutorial)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, grafana, grafana-loki

I'm trying to test Loki on a minikube deployment with 3 nodes following this official tutorial: https://grafana.com/blog/2023/04/12/how-to-collect-and-query-kubernetes-logs-with-grafana-loki-grafana-and-grafana-agent/

After some battling with security context, I use this `value.yml` to launch the Loki instance:

```
minio:
  enabled: true
  securityContext:
    enabled: false
loki:
  podSecurityContext:
    runAsNonRoot: false
    fsGroup: 10
    runAsGroup: 0
    runAsUser: 0
  containerSecurityContext:
    readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
    capabilities:
    allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
gateway:
  replicas: 3
  podSecurityContext:
    runAsNonRoot: false
    fsGroup: 10
    runAsGroup: 0
    runAsUser: 0
  containerSecurityContext:
    readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
    capabilities:
    allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
```

I still quite don't understand how to make the security context work, but it seems that Grafana reaches the Loki instance successfully as depicted in the tutorial.

However, Grafana is always giving me "No data" when using it: [image: grafana_no_data]

For all other actions, I followed the tutorial. But I can't find anything in logs that can help me. I you have any suggestion or hint where I can tend to, I would be very grateful!

Thanks!!

Comment: Hello, maybe a dumb idea, but can you define a query in the "Explore" section? Your second screenshot does not show any query, so this might just be the issue (by default, if you click on "Run query" without query, it'll show "No data"). For that, under "Label filters", just select something like `namespace=loki` and you should be able to see data :)

Comment: @norbjd , thanks for taking the time to reply ! I tried `{stream="stderr"} |= ``` that was mentionned in the tutorial but no luck :(
I'll test your suggestion and I'll tell you if I'm luckier this time!

Comment: @norbjd , it works !! I don't know why they proposed a filter that doesn't work in the tutorial. Setting the namespace was the trick !

Comment: I've tried with the query `{stream="stderr"} |= ""` on a kind cluster and it shows results for me. Maybe you don't have logs written on stderr during the period of time selected? But it's weird as some components like `loki/loki-gateway` are always writing logs on stderr. Can you try on a larger period? Like "Last 3 days"?